# Second Unique Evilities?

Tags: disgaea-5

Passed a Bill in the Dark Assembly and now I got a Celestial Host with an empty Unique Evility Slot. Where and how can get other Unique Evilities?

Do I get it by reincarnation? And will the available Unique Evilities be limited to Generic Characters only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get a class's unique evility by mastering a subclass. Once a subclass is mastered, you can purchase that class's unique evility from the skill shop and equip it in the unique evility slot.

Comment: Based on your answer, it means Unique Character's . . . Unique Evilities won't be available. Alright.